# define plural for new acronym

Tags: glossaries-extra, plural

How can I add a different plural form for the long form of my abbreviation, as the plural form doesn't require an "s" behind it:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newacronym[firstplural={Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen}]{ac:agb}{AGB}{Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\noindent This should write \enquote{(AGB) Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen}:
\glsxtrfull{ac:agb}

\noindent This should write \enquote{(AGBs) Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen}:
\glsxtrfullpl{ac:agb}

\noindent Error: unwanted \enquote{s} after long form of abbreviation
\end{document}
```

And what would be the way to go, if the abbreviation wouldn't require an "s" behind hit (if it would hypothetically be "AGBen"), as the additional option "plural=AGBen" doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the `\newacronym` options `shortplural` and `longplural` set it works as intended:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newacronym[shortplural={AGBsTest},longplural=Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen Test]{ac:agb}{AGB}{Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    \noindent This should write \enquote{(AGB) Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen}:
    \glsxtrfull{ac:agb}
    
    \noindent This should write \enquote{(AGBsTest) Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen Test}:
    \glsxtrfullpl{ac:agb}
    
    \noindent no Error%: unwanted \enquote{s} after long form of abbreviation
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very intuitive without any extra packages or extra commands. Excellent!